# Dropdownlist choice doesn't change data

Tags: c#, asp.net

My dropdownlist isn't working the why I want it to and I can't figure out why. I have looked through stackoverflow and I couldn't find a question that corresponds with mine. My dropdownlist displays all of the names in the database but the data that is attached to the name in the database doesn't appear in the textbox when I select the name. The data for the first name loads correctly in the textbox but after that the data doesn't change. I must be doing something incorrectly when it comes to the datasouceselect code. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private EmployeeContact selectedContact;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if it is not a PostBack,  
        // then bind the Employee data to the ddlContact dropdown list
        if (!IsPostBack) DropDownList1.DataBind();
        // Store the Contact data in the selectedContact object       
        selectedContact = this.GetselectedContact();
        // Display the ContactID from the object in the txtContactID.Text     
        txtContactID.Text = selectedContact.ContactID;
        // Display the Name from the object in the txtFirst.Text 
        txtFirst.Text = selectedContact.Contact_FirstName;
        // Display the Street from the object in the txtLast.Text 
        txtLast.Text = selectedContact.Contact_LastName;
        // Display the City from the object in the txtCell.Text 
        txtCell.Text = selectedContact.Contact_Cell;
        // Display the State from the object in the txtOfficePhone.Text 
        txtOfficePhone.Text = selectedContact.Contact_OfficePhone;
        // Display the Zip from the object in the txtEmail.Text 
        txtEmail.Text = selectedContact.Contact_Email;
        // Display the Phone from the object in the txtPhone.Text 
        txtCompany.Text = selectedContact.Contact_Company;
        // Display the Email from the object in the txtPosition.Text 
        txtPosition.Text = selectedContact.Contact_Position;
        // Display the Phone from the object in the txtZip.Text 
        txtZip.Text = selectedContact.Contact_Zip;
        // Display the Phone from the object in the txtStreet.Text 
        txtStreet.Text = selectedContact.Contact_Street;
        // Display the Phone from the object in the txtCustomerSince.Text 
        txtCustomerSince.Text = selectedContact.Contact_CustomerSinceDate;
        // Display the Phone from the object in the txtDateCreated.Text 
        txtDateCreated.Text = selectedContact.Contact_DateCreated;
        // Display the Phone from the object in the txtNotes.Text 
        txtNotes.Text = selectedContact.Contact_Note;
    }

    private EmployeeContact GetselectedContact()
    {
        // Use DataView to get a datatable 
        DataView Contacts = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        // Format a RowFilter        
        Contacts.RowFilter = string.Format("ContactID = '{0}'", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        // Get a specific row from the selected customer table row 
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)Contacts[0];
        // Instantiate a EmployeeContact object 
        EmployeeContact c = new EmployeeContact();
        // Store the ContactID in the object 
        c.ContactID = row["ContactID"].ToString();
        // Store the FirstName in the object 
        c.Contact_FirstName = row["Contact_FirstName"].ToString();
        // Store the LastName in the object
        c.Contact_LastName = row["Contact_LastName"].ToString();
        // Store the Cellphone in the object
        c.Contact_Cell = row["Contact_Cell"].ToString();
        // Store the OfficePhone in the object
        c.Contact_OfficePhone = row["Contact_OfficePhone"].ToString();
        // Store the Email in the object
        c.Contact_Email = row["Contact_Email"].ToString();
        // Store the Company in the object,
        c.Contact_Company = row["Contact_Company"].ToString();
        // Store the Position in the object, 
        c.Contact_Position = row["Contact_Position"].ToString();
        // Store the Street in the object, 
        c.Contact_Street = row["Contact_Street"].ToString();
        // Store the Zip in the object
        c.Contact_Zip = row["Contact_Zip"].ToString();
        // Store the CustomerSinceDate in the object 
        c.Contact_CustomerSinceDate = row["Contact_CustomerSinceDate"].ToString();
        // Store the DateCreated in the object
        c.Contact_DateCreated = row["Contact_DateCreated"].ToString();
        // Store the Notes in the object
        c.Contact_Note = row["Contact_Note"].ToString();
        // Return the object       
        return c;



    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should register an event handler to dropdrown [change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and load the proper data there. Your current logic only loads the data on page load, which will setup the data for the default dropdown selection but it won't change afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you handle the dropdownlist selection changed code within the "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event handler.

Also, it seems that the ContactID column is a numeric int or something similar, if so, make sure that you remove the single quotes from this line:

```
Contacts.RowFilter = string.Format("ContactID = '{0}'", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

to be:

```
Contacts.RowFilter = string.Format("ContactID = {0}", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Hope it helps.